# why Assertion failure in -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

```
 Assertion failure in -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableViewRowData.m:400

 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',     reason:'Failed to allocate data stores for 997008923 rows in section 0. Consider using fewer rows'
```

my code

```
 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {

   return 1;

  }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

   return [appDelegate.purchaseArray count];

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault         reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}    

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [cartTbl reloadData];

}
```

i didn't get what's problem in this?

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple chooses not to carefully check parameters on many UI objects when you create/modify them, and similarly choose not to use an informative error message when an inconsistency is detected.  But basically the assertion means that you've mucked up something in your table controls.  First make sure that you've actually set both `delegate` and `dataSource`.

Comment: But on closer examination see "Failed to allocate data stores for 997008923 rows in section 0.  Consider using fewer rows".  I doubt that purchaseArray.count actually has that many rows, but somehow that value must be mucked up.  Add an NSLog in numberOfRowsInSection to log the return value.

Comment: it's run proper in simulator but not work in device.

Comment: Which suggests that the problem has something to do with an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Most of the issues I can solve out by resetting simulator and restart Xcode! This seems that you don't have any problem with the code but a something wrong understanding of Xcode compiler.

Comment: i think here is the problem  [appDelegate.purchaseArray count]; check that is the array consist of the data or not.

Answer (score 8):

Check your `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. Maybe you're returning something like `NaN`/`+inf`/`-inf` instead of height. That was my bug.

Remember this is not a crash for `double` and `float` types to divide by zero:

```
double d = 5.0;
double r = d/0.0;
```

So this can help you:

```
if (isnan(r) || isinf(r)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I also had failure in `-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]`. In my case it was caused by set too small `estimatedRowHeight` while using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

for autosizing tableView's cells.
Setting `estimatedRowHeight` to `2.0` instead `1.0` solved problem.

Comment: It worked for me after adding:     
    `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }`

Answer (score 1):

I had an error like this for a different reason. 
My app was working fine, when I decided to change something in my view model (The object that I was binding my table to). I deleted a property, and recompiled. Suddenly the app was throwing this error.

It turned out that there was still a reference to the deleted property in the code that the compiler didn't catch. I had cleaned and rebuilt several times, and the compiler never caught that error that I missed.

Restarting xcode made the build fail, with the offending line now highlighted as an error. Once I fixed that, everything was fine again.

If you encounter bad access errors like this, and see weird stuff in the debugger, like properties with values that should be assigned to other properties, then you might have an error that should have kept your build from compiling that xcode just didn't catch somehow. A restart might fix it - it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

`return [appDelegate.purchaseArray count];` looks like a garbage value. Make sure it's initialized.